# Father of baby is an onen by bris

Tags: mourning-aveilus, brit-milah

We know an onen doesn’t perform any positive commandments, what happens if it’s the 8th day for his son and he needs to perform the bris, is he allowed to do that, or make a shliach, or does it get postponed? I’m referring to an instance where he will be an onen the entire day.

Comment: If there is no father the obligation devolves onto the court. So either way it's happening on the eighth day. The question is just who makes the shaliach (not that there's any harm in both doing so). Check the pitchei teshuva

Comment: I thought about that. Where is the pischei teshuva

Comment: Presumably 341 or thereabouts. Almost certain this is discussed there

Comment: Found it, end of seif bet https://www.sefaria.org/Pitchei_Teshuva_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.341.20 see too taz

Comment: Double AA - this is not obvious. The obligation of the court may not apply if the father is anus and wants to do the mitzvah when he can - see Yevamot 71a and Meiri there; Rambam Mila 1:1-2.